# React-Native how to update dropdown

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-chooser to create my dropdowns and when I select 1 item from dropddown1 I want to update the items from dropdown2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, to make your UI change, you need to update your state. From looking at the docs for `react-native-chooser` it has a callback method called `onSelect`. Here, the currently selected option is returned to you to use. Based on this selected option you can update the state of second dropdown. The important part here is the parent child relationship. In react, a child is only re-rendered if the parent's state is updated (unless otherwise specified). Some pseudocode:

```
// Your method callback
onSelect = (option) => {
  const newOptions = computeNewOptions(option)
  this.setState({options: newOptions})
}

// Your Second dropdown component would take these options in as a prop

render () {
  return (
    <SecondDropDown options={this.state.options} />
 )
}

 // You can then access your options through the props
 export default class SecondDropDown extends React.Component {
   render () {
     let myOptions = renderOptions(this.props.options)
     return (
       <View>
         {myOptions}
       </View>
     )
   }
 }
```

Comment: I understand that, but my dropdown hasn't the property "options". Do you know some module with that property? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to access the options from within your new component. You can wrap your dropdown component in a new component that will handle your rendering.